# jQuery droppable - how to react on hover after a short period of time?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jQuery draggable/droppable to drag (divs) from one list to another.  Both lists have a fixed number of list items, and the list items themselves and can either be empty or already contain a div.

I am dragging a div to a list item. If the list item already contains a div then I would like that div to be pushed down to the list item below it - so as to make way for the div I am dragging.  I can do this with the "over" event in droppable.  But I would like this to happen only after the user has paused there for a cetain period of time, say 0.5 second. How can I do this?

Also, if the user decides not to drop then I would like the displaced item to come back to its original position. Again, what would be the easiest of accomplishing that?

Thanks for your help

William

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to be doing something similar.  In my case, I am using the treeTable plugin.  I want to expand a collapsed tree if it is hovered for some amount of time.  Here is what I have so far.  I just happen to be working on this today.  Note the use of a timeout to delay the operation.

```
var timeout = null;
var clear = function() {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }
}

$(".selector").droppable({
    over: function(e, ui) {
        if (! $(this).is("expanded")) {
            clear();
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).expand();
                timeout = null;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    , out: clear
    , drop: function(e, ui) {
        clear();
        ...
    }
});
```

I'm still having a problem with this.  After one branch gets expanded, the rows below it get pushed down to make room for the expanded branch.  I haven't dropped yet and so I go hover over the first new element in the expanded branch.  The problem is that this element does not get the hoverClass, the first element that got pushed down below the new branch gets it.  It is like jquery doesn't figure out that it got moved down.  I imagine that you are likely to encounter this problem given what you've described.

I was on jquery-1.4.2 but then I updated to jquery-1.6.4 to see if that would fix the problem.  Both versions exhibit the same behavior.  Also, I tested this in Chrome 14.0.835.202, Opera 11.52, Firefox 3.6.23 and IE7.0.5730.13.  It happens the same way in all of them.  So, either jquery has a bug or I've done something to cause this.

About your second question.  I'm not sure I completely understand what you're going after.  Are you looking for the

Comment: I discovered that I needed to add refreshPositions: true to my draggable options to fix the problem that I was seeing.  The jquery documentation says that this hurts performance dramatically so I may look for a way to explicitly refreshPositions when I know that they've potentially changed.

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm definitely going to give this a try.  I am not that experienced in Javascript and was not sure about controlling the timeout.  clearTimeout, setTimeout look good.  For the second question, I want to actually displace the other items on a hover, so if the user doesn't actually drop then I'll need to move the items back to their original positions.  I don't think that should be too difficult but I was just looking for any smart ideas.

Comment: I see what you say about the problem of syncing with the first item that got pushed down.  In my case on the 'out' event I'll want to put everything back the way it was so hopefully I won't have any issues.